# Getting botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found in BOTO3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a list of s3 Objects .i want to get the count of keys in Glacier and archive. Here is my code

```
s3 = boto3.resource(service_name='s3', aws_access_key_id=accesskey, aws_secret_access_key=secretkey)
count = 0
# latest object is a list of s3 keys
for obj in latest_objects:
    try:
        response = s3.Object(Bucket, obj)
        if response.storage_class in ['GLACIER', 'DEEP_ARCHIVE']:
            count=count+1
            print("To be restored: " + obj)
   except Exception as e:
       print(str(e))
       break
```

when I run this code I am getting `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found` for some s3 keys. when I verified these keys are present in bucket. Not sure what's wrong, Again this happens only for some of the keys for the rest of the keys `response = s3.Object(Bucket, obj)` works fine

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to access the failed objects manually to see if its a permission issue? Is it possible the objects get deleted between the time you fetch the list and when you fetch the individual object?

Comment: @jordanm i can access the failed objects manually  and there is no possibility of deletion of object

Comment: Do the keys involve any special symbols that have been encoded or otherwise transformed?

Comment: @AnonCoward No.. THe keys doesn't have any special symbols